# Spring Webflux WebClient stops sending requests after blocking timeout error

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have a Spring Boot Project that uses Spring WebFlux WebClient to make Http Requests to another service.

```
    public APIResponse getResponse(
            APIRequest request) {
        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(uri)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(bulkFetchPricesRequest)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchangeToMono(// method to return mono)
                .block(10);
    }
```

I am facing a strange issue, after some requests, the webClient throws an error of blocking timeout and the subsequent requests to getResponse do not even go to the webserver. Hence, all the calls after one blocking timeout error result in blocking timeout errors.
Any idea why this might be happening?
Error logs -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 10000000000 NANOSECONDS
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
```

WebClient Configuration

```
public class CustomWebClientFactory {

    public static WebClient buildCustomWebClient(
            String baseUrl) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(getReactorClientHttpConnector())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    private static ReactorClientHttpConnector getReactorClientHttpConnector() {
        HttpClient httpClient =
                HttpClient.create()
                        .wiretap(
                                "reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                                LogLevel.DEBUG,
                                AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use blocking in Webflux. You can config timeout in webClient builder. If you would like to delay, use the elementDelay method. It is not a blocker.